# Training data and testing data from the same sensor

Tags: machine-learning, training-data, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

When using learning methords, We have training and testing data.
I'd like to confirm that 
1）whether the training data and testing data must capture from the same sensor 2）What if they are from different sensors?
3) If they must be captured from the same sensor, are there any methods to uniform the data even they are not from the same sensor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need both train and test data from the same sensor because of measurement error and detection bias that's specific to that sensor.  If the test data came from a sensor that's always different from the sensor training data came from, you could have total system failure.  Each sensor has it's own precision, bias, detection limits, etc, so that has to be distributed to both training and testing.

The idea with testing and training is not so much what you are thinking about, but rather the idea that when training the algorithm, the objects used in testing were never used in training.  It's called selection bias.  But you can have have objects from the same sensor used in training or testing.

If, however, the measurement wavelength or angle (pitch) of each sensor is different, then you are dealing more with a problem requiring [MUlti-Signal Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUSIC_(algorithm)) or [Pisarenko harmonic decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisarenko_harmonic_decomposition).

Comment: Thank you. One more question,please . If both training and testing data are from the same sensor, but captured in different views or different pitches, does it matter?

Comment: see the modified end of the example.